# Could a good sound be had from small output amps?

Tags: amplifiers

I'm wondering if it is OK to instead of having your guitar go through a high wattage amp that fills the arena up by itself rather have a small tube amp set to full blast and then maybe set it up and send it through a PA system or other cabs?

Could you still have a decent sound if you do this or will it sound weak?

Comment: 1970, build a bigger amp. 1995 onwards, use whatever you like & mic it up.

Comment: ...and… the sound guy will love you if he's in charge of your mix level, not you ;)

Comment: But will it still sound good? As I understand it tube amps become tremendous when cranked fully.

Comment: It will generally sound better over the PA than it would if you tried to just crank the level from the backline with a bigger amp. Pick your amp, choose your sound, leave the rest to the engineer.

Comment: You can only rely on the sound guy/gal if you brought them with you. A small wattage amp cranked does  not sound like a 50 or 100 watt amp. The transformers aren't as big. Plus you will have no true clean sound. The loudness of an amp has more to do with speaker SPL than wattage.

Comment: Neil Young has for years used a (~15W) tweed Fender Deluxe, and I doubt anyone would accuse him of a weak sound!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely - use a smaller amp and mic it up. Check out pretty much any rock band these days. Sure, some will use the classic Wall of Marshalls (with one or 2 mic'ed up) at big venues, but the majority now use relatively small amps - often between 50 and 150 watts, and have these mic'ed into the PA desk.

This makes it very easy to define your on-stage sound, and gives the sound engineer the flexibility he needs to take that good sound and project it out through the PA.

If you use massive amps, it can be very difficult to tailor your sound to work in different venues, whereas a 50 Watt Marshall can be set to your liking for breakup and overdrive in even small venues.

Comment: Actually, chances are, the "Wall of Marshalls" is actually a "Wall of empty Marshall cabinets with a single cabinet behind the stage micd up".

Comment: As a sound engineer, I can definitely attest to the "the smaller the amp, the bigger the sound" mantra.